# SQL MAX, more JOINS and WHERE

Tags: sql

I have tried to find a solution in other question, but no luck yet.
So I try it this way:
I have 3 tables:

table: w_header:

```
|event_perfno_i|state|reg |issue_date|closing_date|
|--------------|-----|----|----------|------------|
|1111111       |C    |AAA |13-1-2019 |13-1-2019   |
|1111112       |C    |AAA |14-1-2019 |14-1-2019   |
|1111113       |C    |BBB |14-1-2019 |14-1-2019   |
|1111114       |C    |CCC |13-1-2019 |13-1-2019   |
|1111115       |C    |CCC |14-1-2019 |14-1-2019   |
```

table: w_header_crx

```
|event_perfno_i|check|
|--------------|-----|
|1111111       |Y    |
|1111112       |Y    |
|1111113       |Y    |
|1111114       |Y    |
|1111115       |Y    |
```

table ac:

```
|reg    |oper   |status|
|-------|-------|------|
|AAA    |CLK    |0     |
|BBB    |CLK    |0     |
|CCC    |CLK    |0     |
|DDD    |CLK    |0     |
|EEE    |CLK    |0     |
```

With showing the needed fields and using below query its working fine. But if I add other fields, the outcome is not correct and it is showing too much record.

```
SELECT w_header.reg, MAX(w_header.event_perfno_i) AS WO
FROM w_header
LEFT JOIN ac ON w_header.reg = ac.reg
JOIN w_header_crx ON w_header_crx.event_perfno_i =   w_header.event_perfno_i
WHERE (ac.ac_typ IN ('E17', 'E19'))
AND ac.oper = 'CLK'
AND w_header.state = 'C'
AND w_header_crx.check = 'Y'
GROUP BY 
w_header.reg
ORDER BY w_header.reg
```

The SQL does give more records as it should be, despite the conditions.

The expected output should be:

```
|event_perfno_i|reg |issue_date |closing_date|
|--------------|----|-----------|------------|
|1111112       |AAA |14-1-2019  |14-1-2019   |
|1111113       |BBB |14-1-2019  |14-1-2019   |
|1111115       |CCC |14-1-2019  |14-1-2019   |
```

Hope my wish is clear, thx.

Comment: Those ac conditions in the WHERE clause make the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move them to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: I can't figure out your question.  Does the SQL return the correct results (as you say in the paragraph before it)?  Or does it return too many rows ( as said in the paragraph after it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only  the AC present the you should use INNER JOIN and not LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT w_header.reg, MAX(w_header.event_perfno_i) AS WO
FROM w_header
INNER JOIN ac ON w_header.reg = ac.reg
INNER JOIN w_header_crx ON w_header_crx.event_perfno_i =   w_header.event_perfno_i
WHERE (ac.ac_typ IN ('E17', 'E19'))
AND ac.oper = 'CLK'
AND w_header.state = 'C'
AND w_header_crx.check = 'Y'
GROUP BY  w_header.reg
ORDER BY w_header.reg
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge... and I am sorry if I am not clear enough. I am not so experienced... 
I mean if add  w_header.closing_date, the outcome is different than without it.

`SELECT w_header.reg, MAX(w_header.event_perfno_i) AS WO,
w_header.closing_date
FROM w_header
INNER JOIN ac ON w_header.reg = ac.reg
INNER JOIN w_header_crx ON w_header_crx.event_perfno_i =   w_header.event_perfno_i
WHERE (ac.ac_typ IN ('E17', 'E19'))
AND ac.oper = 'CLK'
AND w_header.state = 'C'
AND w_header_crx.check = 'Y'
GROUP BY  w_header.reg
ORDER BY w_header.reg`

Comment: Two considerations .. the first is that in SO it is not fair to change a question after you get a right answer .. if you add a condition to a query it is obvious that the result is different .. it is equally obvious that this is a question different from previously. .. as I told you before .. you should mark this answer (if it is right) as correct .. and post a new question with exact directions.
The second .. you should post the new question with clear and consistent sample data (actual query in use, sample data, current result and desired result)

Comment: In this way the whole community of SO could help you and not just me .
Instead you keep repeating that first was fine and now that you have changed is not good .. SO is not a service of writing the code on request but a site where you ask a question and you usually get a (right) answer .. If you post a new question, you can possibly send me a comment with the relative link